# How to get rails-admin not to duplicate model names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Using rails-admin, the dashboard is displaying models twice, consider the below screenshot:

[image]

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == Cancan ==
  # config.authorize_with :cancan

  ## == Pundit ==
  # config.authorize_with :pundit

  ## == PaperTrail ==
  # config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version' # PaperTrail >= 3.0.0

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  config.actions do
    allowable_models = ['Lab', 'Order']

    dashboard do
      only allowable_models
    end

    index do
      only allowable_models
    end

    show do
      only allowable_models
    end

    new do
      only allowable_models
    end

    edit do
      only allowable_models
    end

    delete do
      only allowable_models
    end

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
end
```

It doesn't really matter that the objects are being displayed twice, but as far as I understand this gem, the objects shouldn't be displayed twice, and I'd like to fix it.  Any thoughts on what to be digging into here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your rails admin initializer.

Comment: @AlokSwain added thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue recently. The solution was mentioning specifically the model names in *config/initializers/rails_admin.rb*:

```
config.included_models = ["FirstModel", "SecondModel", "ThirdModel"]
```